# ¿Qué significa "darse un escorpión" en México?

Tags: coloquialismos, méxico

Estuve escuchando un podcast presentado por dos cuates del DF. En algún momento leyeron una anécdota que se les enviara, y ésta decía:

> ...Ya bien pedo, se me olvidó que mis padres estaban al lado mío, y me empecé a *dar un escorpión*. Cuando mi mamá me vio, dijo "no te pases de listo".

¿Qué significa la frase en bastardilla? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sorpresa mayúscula al comprobar las entrada de escorpión en el [diccionario de americanismos](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=escorpion) y ver que en México es un **Reptil**

Comment: Es que en muchas partes de México al arácnido se le llama *alacrán*.

Comment: pon un enlace al podcast, a ver si lo podemos sacar si no por el contexto o los comentarios...

Comment: Veo que has hecho la misma [pregunta en Wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/darse-un-escorpi%C3%B3n-m%C3%A9xico.3698671/) y que te han respondido. Si la respuesta te cuadra, no dudes en publicarla aquí también (aquí animamos a que la gente se responda sus propias preguntas para crear más contenido).

Comment: Aún no me ha llegado ninguna respuesta de la que me fíe. Aquí es el enlace del podcast donde lo escuché, minuto 43.  http://tun.in/tjV0OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En México, "Darse un escorpión o un escorpionazo", se dice cuando una persona toma una botella de una bebida alcohólica abierta y con una sola mano la apunta hacia su propia boca sin que la botella toque los labios, al doblar la espalda para poder tomar el liquido se forma una figura que asemeja a un escorpión, siendo el brazo con la botella la cola del escorpión y el liquido el veneno del mismo.